# DNS. Разные ответы разным IP

Tags: bind, bind9

Есть сервер с установленным DNS-сервером *BIND9*. В организации некоторые зоны (пусть это будет, для примера, `google.com`) должны блокироваться, поэтому *BIND* выдаёт для них IP-адрес заглушки.

1. Как сделать, чтобы для определённых IP-адресов *BIND* выдавал не адрес заглушки, а "настоящий", запрашивая его у внешних серверов?
2. Как сделать, чтобы для определённых IP-адресов и определённых поддоменов (например, `play.google.com`) *BIND* выдавал не адрес заглушки, а настоящий, но в то же время все остальные поддомены перенаправлял на заглушки?

Comment: В bind9 поддерживаются т.н. `view` - позволяют одноимённые зоны DNS отдавать разным клиентам с разным содержимым. В одном случае зона может быть типа slave, в другом - master (с заглушкой.) Копать надо в эту сторону. Не знаю только, как управлять отдельной записью в зоне (чтобы только один хост указывал на заглушку.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для выдачи разных ответов разным клиентам вам надо настроить view. Для этого в named.conf делаем примерно такие действия:

```
acl "granted" {     -- Объявляем ACL описывающую клиентов, для которых нужны особые правила
     10.0.64.0/24;
     10.10.10.5;
};
```

Все настройки, касающиеся описания зон, включая зоны `hint` выносим в view, причем большинство настроек в view дублируем. Если зон много имеет смысл вынести их описания в отдельный файл и включать его include:

```
/* view для избранных, должна стоять первой */
view "granted" {
 match-clients {granted;};  /* Тут имя ACL с "особыми" клиентами */
 recursion yes;
 allow-recursion { any; };
 zone "." in {type hint; file "/var/bind/root.cache";};
 zone "example.com." {type master; file "pri/example.com";};
 ...
 include "/etc/bind/z.named.conf";
};

/* view для всех остальных */
view "all" {
 match-clients {any;};
 recursion yes;
 allow-recursion { any; };
 zone "." in {type hint; file "/var/bind/root.cache";};

 zone "google.com" {type master; file "pri/google.blackhole";}; /* Тут зона-заглушка */

 zone "example.com." {type master; file "pri/example.com";};
 ...
 include "/etc/bind/z.named.conf";
};
```

Это решит вашу первую проблему, т.е. для клиентов с IP указанных в ACL "granted" описан отдельный взгляд на мир, где может не быть заглушек или быть не такие заглушки как у остальных.

С вторым вопросом сложнее, потому как решить его "правильно" в bind нельзя (или мне не известно как). А для "не правильного" решения нам придется описать настоящие *правильные* ответы в своем файле для зоны-заглушки. При этом там возможно придется описать даже ip-адреса, а это значит, что за зоной постоянно надо будет следить, на случай если оригинальный сайт изменит свои настройки. Для тестовой заглушки всего google.com кроме play.google.com мне пришлось сделать следующее описание зоны:

```
$TTL 432000     ; 5 days
@       IN     SOA      @    email.ru. (
                        2004100602
                        21600       ; Refrash 6 hours
                        1800        ; Retry 30 min
                        1209600     ; Expire  2 weeks
                        432000 )    ; Minimum 5 days

             IN      NS ns.mysite.ru.
             IN      A  10.0.1.2
play         IN      NS ns1.google.com.
play.l       IN      NS ns1.google.com.
wide-play.l  IN      NS ns1.google.com.
ns1          IN      A  216.239.32.10
*            IN      A  10.0.1.2    ; На все не описанные адреса из зоны отвечать адресом 10.0.1.2
```

В данном файле `10.0.1.2` и `ns.mysite.ru.` IP и имя моего NS сервера, т.е. того, где располагается эта заглушка. Конкретно имя `play.google.com` это алиас на имя `play.l.google.com.`, которое алиас на `wide-play.l.google.com.`. Поэтому мне пришлось описать в зоне явные указания ходить за получением правильных ответов на гугловский NS `ns1.google.com`. Но он так же в нашей зоне и попадет под заглушку, поэтому пришлось описать сам NS, причем указать действительный ip адрес гугловской NS. Конечно можно написать список IP для надежности, но если гугл поменяет адреса всех своих NS серверов - то нам надо будет их менять в конфиге.

Comment: если есть где поэкспериментировать, то для зоны `play.google.com` можно попробовать указать `type forward; forwarders {127.0.0.1;};`, а  `127.0.0.1` добавить в `acl "granted"`. кажется, должно получиться. // смысл: обращаться за резолвингом `play.google.com` к самому себе.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Я пробовал, но не прокатило. причем даже с гугловскими серверами в качестве форвардеров и с 127.0.0.1 то же. Почему - для меня загадка

Comment: @Mike Видимо, не прокатило потому, что BIND не обращается сам к себе через `loopback` за ответом. Скорее всего, он выбирает `view` при получении запроса клиента и дальше работает "внутри" него. За ответ огромное спасибо!

Comment: @kff, зона — это, в первую очередь, soa-запись. которую гугловские сервера не вернут: ведь для них `play.google.com` — отнюдь не зона. так что с помощью *bind-а* «финт», увы, не выйдет. он слишком «правильный». возможно, выйдет с помощью чего-нибудь более примитивного, типа *dnsmasq*.

Answer (score -1):

Запустить несколько демонов с разными конфигурационными файлами и слушающих разные интерфейсы или разные порты. С помощью iptables перенаправлять запросы от разных адресов разным демонам.

Comment: В bind есть возможность задавать разное содержимое зон клиентам из разных сетей. Опции конфигурационных файлов: `acl`, `view`, `match-clients`. Без `iptables` точно можно обойтись.